# I want to change the datepicker for my mobile website on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, safari, datepicker

Currently the `datepickers` trigger the default `iOS datepicker` with `dd-mm-yyyy` format. I would like it to trigger the `dddd-dd-mm-yyyy` format so users are better at picking the correct date because they can see the actual day of the week. 
**Is this possible for a mobile website?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing it for mobile website. But we can change format of default iOS date picker if you want. It's directly not possible through date picker. There is another component called UIPickerView in iOS, through which we can achieve this. Check how to create UIPickerView for mobile website and place the values you want in pickerView.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing more research on the subject I have found that it is possible to use `datetime-local`. This triggers the native datepicker with ddd-dd-mm format but also accounts for the year (so scrolling over december 31 will make the date object move to the next year). This workaround has issues with IE though, so is not a universal solution.